# Input val() at keyup event is delayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup

If you type two characters – e.g. the number '12' - quickly into an input field and log the val() at each keyup event, we get two keyup events but the `val()` is `12` (in my example) both times.

```
$(".myInput").keyup(function(e){
  console.log("val() = " + $(this).val());
});
```

Expected output when typing '12':

```
val() = 1
val() = 12
```

Observed output when typing '12':

```
val() = 12
val() = 12
```

**[Fiddle HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/qyodk3m0/)**.

Is there an inbuilt delay in updating `val()`? This feels like a bug but I see the same behaviour across Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

Comment: Listen to the `input` event instead -> https://jsfiddle.net/hhq3xm08/ The problem is that you're pressing the next key before the `keyup` event is fired on the first key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're pressing `2` before the `keyup` event for `1` has fired.  It won't fire until you release the key, but you can type the next character before releasing the first.  Since the input box then contains `12` before either `keyup` event fires, that's what `val()` reports back to you on both events.

Comment: Of course. The val() changes at keypress. It's been a long week!

Answer (score 1):

Use `input` event it's very useful to track input fields changes, and it will prevent the behavior you have in this case :

```
$("#testField").on('input', function(e){
   $('.outputContainer').append("val() = " + $(this).val() + "m keycode = "+ e.keyCode +"\n");
});
```

Hope this helps.

---

### Snippet

```js
$(".outputContainer").html("Type a number fast in the field above \n");
$("#testField").on('input', function(e){
  $('.outputContainer').append("val() = " + $(this).val() + "m keycode = "+ e.keyCode +"\n");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="testField" type="number">

<div class="outputContainer">
test
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I had somehow forgotten that the input value updates at input and not at keyup. Takes an SO post to realise the obvious sometimes.